# Standard deviation, mean, max and min extraction just inside 5-95 quantiles values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to extraction the mean, max, min and sd extraction inside 5-95 quantiles for the variables `B2`,
`B3`, `B4`, `B8`, `NDVI`, `SAVI`, `SIPI`, `SR`, `RGI`, `TVI`, `MSR`, `PRI`, `GNDVI`, `PSRI`, `GCI` aggregate by `AGE` and `ESPAC` variables inside a **CMPC** table:

My CMPC SQL table (`[PROJECT_ID].spectra_calibration.CMPC`) create inside BigQuery:

```
Rows: 55.310
Columns: 27
Database: BigQueryConnection
$ x          <dbl> -52.5502, -52.5501, -52.5501, -52.5501, -52.5501, -52.5500, -52.5500, -52.5500, -52.5500, -52.5500,~
$ y          <dbl> -30.8295, -30.8297, -30.8296, -30.8295, -30.8294, -30.8298, -30.8297, -30.8296, -30.8295, -30.8294,~
$ stand      <chr> "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO001A", "ABRANJO0~
$ date       <chr> "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-28", "~
$ B2         <dbl> 213, 205, 181, 207, 216, 205, 165, 161, 173, 182, 181, 259, 227, 190, 153, 147, 160, 164, 194, 210,~
$ B3         <dbl> 361.0, 362.0, 346.0, 352.0, 369.0, 330.0, 290.0, 326.0, 334.0, 332.0, 325.0, 375.0, 352.0, 307.0, 2~
$ B4         <dbl> 227.0, 233.0, 198.0, 207.0, 209.0, 227.0, 178.0, 164.0, 180.0, 207.0, 209.0, 267.0, 269.0, 194.0, 1~
$ B8         <dbl> 3033.0, 3307.0, 3322.0, 3232.0, 3241.0, 3065.0, 3306.0, 3422.0, 3427.0, 3392.0, 3165.0, 3206.0, 298~
$ NDVI       <dbl> 0.86074, 0.86836, 0.88750, 0.87962, 0.87884, 0.86209, 0.89782, 0.90853, 0.90019, 0.88497, 0.87611, ~
$ SAVI       <dbl> 4549.379, 4960.386, 4982.905, 4847.897, 4861.397, 4597.380, 4958.915, 5132.925, 5140.417, 5087.903,~
$ SIPI       <dbl> 1.00499, 1.00911, 1.00544, 1.00000, 0.99769, 1.00775, 1.00416, 1.00092, 1.00216, 1.00785, 1.00947, ~
$ SR         <dbl> 13.36123, 14.19313, 16.77778, 15.61353, 15.50718, 13.50220, 18.57303, 20.86585, 19.03889, 16.38647,~
$ RGI        <dbl> 0.62881, 0.64365, 0.57225, 0.58807, 0.56640, 0.68788, 0.61379, 0.50307, 0.53892, 0.62349, 0.64308, ~
$ TVI        <int> 173720, 189600, 193360, 187300, 188320, 174400, 192160, 201960, 200980, 196100, 182000, 180660, 166~
$ MSR        <dbl> 3.65530, 3.76738, 4.09607, 3.95140, 3.93792, 3.67453, 4.30964, 4.56792, 4.36336, 4.04802, 3.89147, ~
$ PRI        <dbl> -0.25784, -0.27690, -0.31309, -0.25939, -0.26154, -0.23364, -0.27473, -0.33881, -0.31755, -0.29183,~
$ GNDVI      <dbl> 0.78727, 0.80267, 0.81134, 0.80357, 0.79557, 0.80560, 0.83871, 0.82604, 0.82239, 0.82170, 0.81375, ~
$ PSRI       <dbl> -0.04418, -0.03901, -0.04455, -0.04486, -0.04937, -0.03361, -0.03388, -0.04734, -0.04494, -0.03685,~
$ GCI        <dbl> 7.40166, 8.13536, 8.60116, 8.18182, 7.78320, 8.28788, 10.40000, 9.49693, 9.26048, 9.21687, 8.73846,~
$ ID_PROJETO <int> 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245,~
$ PROJETO    <chr> "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", "ABRANJO", ~
$ CD_TALHAO  <chr> "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "001A", "00~
$ DATA_PLANT <chr> "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "2008-07-15", "~
$ ESPECIE    <chr> "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", "SALIGNA", ~
$ ESPAC      <chr> "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.5x2.14", "3.~
$ AGE_1      <dbl> 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.~
$ AGE        <int> 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,~
```

Reference to a sample table in CSV: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_ds_CSV.csv

My file schema is:

```
x   FLOAT   NULLABLE    
y   FLOAT   NULLABLE    
stand   STRING  NULLABLE    
date    STRING  NULLABLE    
B2  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
B3  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
B4  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
B8  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
NDVI    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
SAVI    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
SIPI    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
SR  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
RGI FLOAT   NULLABLE    
TVI INTEGER NULLABLE    
MSR FLOAT   NULLABLE    
PRI FLOAT   NULLABLE    
GNDVI   FLOAT   NULLABLE    
PSRI    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
GCI FLOAT   NULLABLE    
ID_PROJETO  INTEGER NULLABLE    
PROJETO STRING  NULLABLE    
CD_TALHAO   STRING  NULLABLE    
DATA_PLANT  STRING  NULLABLE    
ESPECIE STRING  NULLABLE    
ESPAC   STRING  NULLABLE    
AGE_1   FLOAT   NULLABLE    
AGE INTEGER NULLABLE
```

I try to do the query for just one variable (`B2`) for the test and the desirable query is something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AGE, ESPAC
,PERCENTILE_DISC(B2,0.05) OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC) AS P05_B2
,PERCENTILE_DISC(B2,0.95) OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC) AS P95_B2
,MIN(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS B2_min
,AVG(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS B2_mean
,MAX(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS B2_max
,stddev(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS B2_sd
FROM `[PROJECT_ID].spectra_calibration.CMPC`
ORDER BY AGE, ESPAC
```

The basic idea is a final result calculated (MAX, MIN, SD and AVG) with the B2 values only with values > P05_B2 and < P95_B2. I'd like something with B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2 conditions. My desirable output is:

```
#     AGE ESPAC    B2_mean B2_max B2_min B2_sd 
# 1    -2 4X1.85      125.   175    75    14.2    
# 2    -1 4X1.85      153.   300    67    34.0   
# 3     0 4X1.85      419.   928.   71   274.     
# 4     1 4X1.85      344.   683   129    83.4    
# 5    11 3.5x2.14    137.   259    70    29.8    
# 6    12 3.5x2.14    150.   298    67.5  23.6    
# 7    13 3.5x2.14    130.   302    70    35.3    
# ...
```

Please any help with this query construction?

Comment: Could you resend an updated CSV file with BigQuery supported [Schema and data types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#standard_sql_data_types) as the CSV file which you have provided throws up multiple [errors](https://github.com/sandy0298/Bigquery/blob/main/comment.png) while loading into BigQuery with schema as Auto-detect.

Comment: Thank you @Sandeep Mohanty I update the csv file as request and show too the table schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions (

```
MIN(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2) ,

AVG(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2),
 
MAX(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2)
```

)

with operators like **< , >** will return a **Binary value** i.e **True/False** rather than providing the min, max and avg for the expression as per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#operator_precedence).

For the functions like MIN(), MAX(),AVG(), STDDEV(), you need to specify a column so that the functions will scan the column and will provide the output.

**For example :**

```
Select MIN(AGE) as minmum_age from my-project.dataset2.tab1;
```

Here the MIN() function will scan through the AGE column and will provide the minimum value in that column i.e  -2

The sample Query that you have provided throws errors when running in BigQuery.

**Error:**

[image]

For reference you can check the below modified query and output also.

**Query :**

```
select DISTINCT AGE, ESPAC,P05_B2 ,
MIN(B2 > P05_B2 AND B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS MIN_B2,
MAX(B2 > P05_B2 AND B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS MAX_B2
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT AGE, ESPAC,B2
,PERCENTILE_DISC(B2,0.05) OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC) AS P05_B2
,PERCENTILE_DISC(B2,0.95) OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC) AS P95_B2
FROM `my-project.dataset2.tab1`
ORDER BY AGE, ESPAC
)
```

**Output :**

[image]

As per your requirement, I tried writing a query with your dataset and I am getting results similar to your output.

Could you try the same on your end and let me know if this works for you.

**Query :**

```
SELECT AGE,ESPAC,AVG (B2) AS B2_mean,

MAX(B2)  AS B2_max,

MIN(B2)  AS B2_min,

STDDEV(B2)  AS B2_sd  FROM (

SELECT *,

FROM (

SELECT *,

PERCENTILE_DISC(B2, 0.05)  OVER () AS P05_B2,

PERCENTILE_DISC(B2, 0.95)  OVER () AS P95_B2,

FROM `my-project.dataset2.tab1` 
ORDER BY AGE,ESPAC ) WHERE B2 > P05_B2 AND B2 < P95_B2

) GROUP BY AGE,ESPAC ORDER BY AGE,ESPAC
```

**Output :**

[image]

Please note that the output presented above is based on the sample CSV file that is provided. The aggregated values might change based on the dataset.

Comment: Thanks, @Sandepp nice solution!!!!!!

Comment: Glad to help @Leprechault

Comment: So sorry @Sandepp Monhanty, but I need to re-open the question. I make some careful tests today and the results in not been corrected yet. The code limiting the mean/min/etc to a reduced set that excludes values below 5th and above 95th but I don't know why I don't have just one value for AGE -2 and 12 and ESPAC 4x1.85 and 3.5x2.14 (like in the desirable output ) for example and it is clear that we need ORDER BY AGE, ESPAC. I believe that the code returns all the values below 5th and above 95th.

Comment: Hi @Leprechault I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sandepp Monhanty. Now, its OK and I tested the results, just only `GROUP BY AGE,ESPAC`. Your solution is very helpful for me!!!!